# JavaScript regular expression to get valid date format "MM/dd/yyyy"

Tags: javascript, regex

I am learning JavaScript Regular Expression.

I am writing a function to check valid date format, 'MM/dd/yyyy'.

```
function isValidDate(dateStr) {
    var result = dateStr.match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(199\d)|([2][0]\d{2})$/);
    if(result)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

It works fine, but I got some issues.

```
01/01/2014 // return true
01/1/2014  // return true (it should return false)
1/01/2014  // return true (it should return false)
```

I don't want the function to return true when the month.length is 1.  I want to make sure that the month.length == 2 && the date.length == 2.  How can I modify my regular expression?

**EDIT**

```
01/01/20 // return true (it should return false)
```

How can I make sure that the year.length == 4?

Comment: Why did you make the first character optional if that's not what you really wanted? Did you know what you were doing when you typed `0?`?

Comment: Your regexp already requires that the year length is 4. However, the parentheses are in the wrong place, so it only matches `M/D/199x` or `20xx`, not `M/D/20xx`.

Comment: It looks like you are using to learn or possibley homework, but be aware that you shouldn't use this for parsing dates, as 09/31/xxxx etc would be considered valid dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern, the leading zeros are optional because of the 'zero-or-one' quantifiers (`?`). Simply remove them to make the zeros required.

Also, you need to wrap your year portion in a single group, and `[2][0]` can be simplified to `20`. Try this:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(199\d|20\d{2})$/
```

Finally, You can simply use [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) rather than [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
function isValidDate(dateStr) {
    return /^(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(199\d|20\d{2})$/.test(dateStr);
}
```

This will give you the results you want:

- `isValidDate("01/01/2014")` → `true`
- `isValidDate("01/1/2014")` → `false`
- `isValidDate("1/01/2014")` → `false`

Comment: And how can I make sure that the year.length == 4?

Comment: It returns true when the date is '01/01/20'

Comment: @KimchiMan [No it doesn't](http://jsfiddle.net/06ngx0vk/). Please look again at my code.

Comment: @tenub Returns `true` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[\-\/\.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\-\/\.](19|20)\d\d$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd go with:

`/^(0)[1-9]{1}|(1)[0-2]{1}\/([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|3[0-1]{1})\/\d{4}$/`

It depends on your application -- you said you wanted four digit years, but didn't specify recent years, so I left out the restriction on dates being > 199*

You can test it here: http://regexr.com/39ae1